# Route outbound kubernetes traffic to NAT(in aws)

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a Nat instance deployed in aws.
I'd like to deploy a k8 nodes in private subnet and be able to route outbound external traffic through that NAT.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in AWS - your worker nodes do not even need a public IP, they can egress through the NAT gateway. You will see NAT Gateways as an option under VPC. Check AWS documentation to ensure this is set up correctly [AWS NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)
This is how our staging environment is set up. Using EKS in AWS, they have some defaults that are useful (like the role for worker nodes).